# status bar looks strange when launched in iOS 8+ device (Master-Detail template used)

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

My app is developed when iOS version was 6.

Recently I want to renew my app, but status bar looks strange.

I do not code so unique codes in my project, so I wonder why 
battery image is shown but percentage or time clock is not shown.
(application is only run on iPad, not on iPhone)

[image: this problem]

I heard UISplitViewController is much changed after iOS8, so
maybe it is a reason.
(My app based on Master-Detail template in Xcode)

So, if anyone had a same problem and had fixed it,
tell me the reason and solution plz  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following suggestions :

1. Configure your .plist file like this ,

   View controller-based status bar appearance : NO
2. For each view controller change the status bar's Simulated Metrics property, in storyboard, from "inferred" to "Light Content"

And also go through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html).